# Efficient way to print the entries of a Java Map as a table?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, treemap

I'm just starting to work with the Java Map data type and I was wondering if there is an easy way to print out all the key-value pairs as a table?

For example, say I want to count the frequencies of a character in a string and store it into a Map.

So the string "all the way down the stream" results in printing to a console the following

```
Character Frequencies
---------------------
' '        5
'l'        2
't'        3
'h'        2
```

ect

From what I've found, the toString() on map will return something to the tune of "{   =5, l=2, t=3, h=2}"

Which is great, but building large tables off of the toString structure would be slow. Is there a cleaner, faster way to do this other than String operations?

Comment: What do you mean by table? Are you referring to `JTable`?

Comment: You asked for a way that is "efficient", "easy", "cleaner", and "faster". Which one do you want?

Comment: You can iterate over all entries and print them one by one. Knowing the appropriate column width beforehand could be a problem.

Comment: Just printing a table to a console. Also, I guess the cleanest way to do this is preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your map key-value pair is of type String-Integer, you can iterate through a Map using:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : theMap.entrySet()) {
    entry.getKey(); // gives you the 'Character' key
    entry.getValue(); // gives you the 'Frequencies' value
}
```

Of course, you will need to do the pretty printing.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see any obvious way to iterate over a Map.

Comment: Note that depending on the Map implementation used, the entries might not be in any particularly meaningful order.

Comment: Correct. I assumed that he's using `TreeMap` since the question is tagged with 'treemap'